# Find count of direct reports for manager in R

Tags: r, countif

I'm looking for R's version of Excel's "COUNTIFS" function to find the number of direct reports for a specific employee based on if they are a manager.  I have tried the group-by function and the length function but cannot find the get the correct output. A simple version of my data looks like this:

- employee:      a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
- manager:       g,a,a,a,b,b,e,c

Where the output should look like this:

- direct report: 3,2,1,0,1,0,0,0

Answer (score 2):

```
table(factor(manager, employee))

a b c d e f g h 
3 2 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

To do a COUNTIF you can simply sum up the result of a comparison. In this case you say `sum(manager == "a")`. `manager == "a"` will give a vector

```r
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

if you sum that up R will coerce the boolean to integers so that each TRUE will add 1 to the sum.

In your case we need `sapply` to repeat this step for each element of  `employee` (my guess is, the 7 element in your "direct report" example should be 1 instead of 0).

```r
employee <- letters[1:8]
manager <-  c("g","a","a","a","b","b","e","c")

sapply(employee, function(x) sum(manager == x))
#> a b c d e f g h 
#> 3 2 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>